# Error in adding item to a QLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to add an item in a QLayout (in PyQT5) as follows:

```
def add_parts_BC(self):
        """This adds a tab with part B and C"""

        BCVerticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        partB = PartB()
        partC = PartC()

        BCVerticalLayout.addWidget(PartB, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        BCVerticalLayout.addWidget(PartC)

        # add the layout to the tabbed widget layout
        self.tabbedWidget.addTab(BCVerticalLayout, "Part B and C")
```

I then get the following error message:

```
BCVerticalLayout.addWidget(PartB, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
TypeError: QBoxLayout.addWidget(QWidget, int stretch=0, Qt.Alignment alignment=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'
```

I do not know where things are done wrong. Any idea?

By the way, PartA and PartB looks like this:

```
class PartA(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # more code here


class PartB(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # more code here
```

Comment: Can you post code of `PartB` and `PartC` ?...They seem to be classes or what?

Comment: Iron Fist: Yes both PartB and PartC are classes inheriting from QWidget.

Comment: Can we see some code relating to them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a TYPO error:

```
partB = PartB() #name of object with lower case p
partC = PartC()

BCVerticalLayout.addWidget(PartB, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop) #name of object with upper case p
```

so it should be:

```
partB = PartB() 
partC = PartC()

BCVerticalLayout.addWidget(partB, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
```

Comment: Never thought of that at all, thank you very much it works.

Comment: No pblm...consider accepting my answer if you are satisfied with it..:)